# Change color of selected option only

Tags: jquery, css

I have a selector sitting in a table cell. The table row has a color, so using CSS I can change the drop-down's background to the same color by using `background-color:inherit;`   However, it changes the color of the entire box with all options.

Is it possible to change the color of the selected option only, if not with CSS perhaps with a help of jQuery?

Comment: Can you show us your html and css?  Fyi... styling select boxes is terribly difficult!

Comment: Probably not, no; browsers seem to have limited access to the styling of `select` elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything is possible with jQuery :)
You should try this:

```
$('.mySelect').change(function () {
    $(this).find('option').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', 'red');
}).trigger('change');
```

And here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ronn's answer takes into account the selected item when inactive and when clicked on and expanded.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do it by first setting the background color of the SELECT element to what I wanted resulting in all options being that color. Then I made all the options a specific color scheme. Finally I made the selected option the same color scheme as the SELECT element so the option shows the same color in the drop down list.

```
$.each($('select'), function(i,v) {

    theElement = $(v);
    theID = theElement.attr('id');

    // Set the SELECT input element to green background with white text

    theElement.css('background-color', 'green');
    theElement.css('color', 'white');

    // Set all the options to another color (note transparant will show the green)

    $('#'+theID).find('option').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#'+theID).find('option').css('color', 'black');

    // Finally set the selected option to the same values as the SELECT element

    $('#'+theID).find('option:selected').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('#'+theID).find('option:selected').css('color', 'white');
});
```

Comment: the answer was up there since Oct 12 2011! Besides, it was accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with jQuery.  I may be wrong (see David Thomas' comment), but try:

```
$("option[value='myValue']").css('background-color', 'red');
```