# Remove multiple select default background

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I have this multiple select for which I want to change the default background for an individidual `<option>`

```
<select size="8" name="lstSelectedPackages" style="width:100%">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/180/

Thank you!

Comment: `select { background: red; }`?

Comment: which background..?? body bg.?? select bg..?? div bg..?? what..??

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar only selected line background.

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789741/html-how-to-set-background-color-of-item-in-select-element).

Comment: You can in Certain browsers, but not in Chrome.

Comment: @Andy in firefox and IE I want to modify that

Comment: Not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089442/changing-the-background-color-of-the-selected-options-in-a-select-box

Answer (score 2):

Just change the background on style as below

```
<select size="8" name="lstSelectedPackages" style="width:100%; background:#fff999">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
```

if you want to do it for all the select tag, then you can add below code on css

```
select{
   background: #fff999;
}
```

You can use jquery for that though as follows:

```
$("option:selected").css{"background", "#fff999"}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the background of all select only for selected line :|

Comment: for selected option you can try this one **option[selected]{background:#fff999}** Note: this may be browsers dependent though

Answer (score 2):

If `jQuery` is best for you then i am sure this will surly help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {

        $("select option:selected").each(function ()
        {
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        });

    });

</script>
<select name="garden">
    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option>Bushes</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle showing how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/181/

It should be noted that selects are notoriously unreliable when it comes to styling cross-browser so your styling may not appear consistently across all browsers/version.

```
select {
    height:50px;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

If you only want one select to have a specific background color/style use a class to define it e.g.

```
<select class="my-select-class">
 <option>2</option>
</select>

.my-select-class {
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

It's not recommended to use inline styles on your web pages as this makes them a nightmare to maintain down the line.

Stick to external stylesheets.

Comment: I don't want to change the background of all select only for selected line :|

Comment: @burebistaruler - Sorry, I see what you mean now, as far as I know that color is set by the operating system and cannot be changed. There may be a JavaScript solution but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

use `background-color`

```
select{
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;

}
```

**updated**

using jquery.

```
$('option').css('background', 'none');
$('option:selected').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ux4DD/182/)

Comment: I don't want to change the background of all select only for selected line :|

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the answer like this

Jquery

```
$('.mySelect').change(function () {
$(this).find('option').css('background-color', 'transparent');
$(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', 'red');
}).trigger('change');
```

Html

```
<select class="mySelect">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/)
  [Refrence link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741722/change-color-of-selected-option-only)